# Weak-linking multiple frameworks for iPhone Apps (-weak_framework)

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, linker, weak-linking

How do I specify -weak_framework  for multiple frameworks while compiling iPhone apps for older deployment targets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the **Build Phases** section of your target, you've got the list of the linked frameworks.

For each one, you can select **Required** or **Optional**, optional meaning weak.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my application, I am accessing Twitter.framework and Accounts.framework that need to be weekly-linked. I've set the "Link Binaries With Libraries" to "Optional" for these frameworks. However, I still get the following errors and the application is crashing in previous Deployment targets: warning: Unable to read symbols from "Accounts" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Twitter" (not yet mapped into memory).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Add a linker flag -weak_framework `<`framework_name> Check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html