# Checking CIFilter is available in current iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-image, respondstoselector

I would like to use some of the functionality of iOS5 but still build for iOS4 compaitibly but i'm having an issue. Typically i would use the `respondsToSelector:` but i'm not exactly sure whether this is the correct method, or if it is what exactly i should insert.

I'm trying to use CIFilter which, from what i understand, is only available within iOS5+, how would check to see whether this is available within the currently installed OS?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `NSClassFromString()` to determine if the class exists in the current version of iOS.

```
Class filterClass = NSClassFromString(@"CIFilter");

if (!filterClass)
{
    // Must be less than 5.0. CIFilter doesn't exist.
}
else
{
    // CIFilter is available
    CIFilter *filter = [filterClass filterWithName:@"somefilter"];
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark

That looks like it's working, although i'm trying to run the app within the iOS 4.3 simulator and i get the following error

"dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
  Referenced from: /Users/JohnSlater/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/C964F4D5-FAD1-4348-895D-551FBD923915/SXIWalls.app/SXIWalls
  Reason: image not found "

Which i'm starting to think is because the CoreImage framework altogether isn't available in iOS4. How would i go about getting around this error?

Comment: Hi guys, this actually answered that question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385444/weak-linking-multiple-frameworks-for-iphone-apps-weak-framework

Mark answered the first question correctly, cheers Mark :D

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIComicEffect")
        {
            // Filter exist
        }
        else
        {
            // Filter does not exist
        }
```