# Can we integrate Facebook SDK 3.1 in IOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS - runs on iOS6, but crashes on iOS 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610078/facebook-sdk-3-1-for-ios-runs-on-ios6-but-crashes-on-ios-5-x)

I have integrated `Facebook sdk 3.1` in `iOS 6.0` and it works fine but here my question is that can we integrate the same `sdk 3.1` in `iOS 5.0`?.

Comment: Yes it is supported and you might try to proper homework before posting the question here..
take a look at the following link 
[facebook sdk 3.1 in IOS 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610078/facebook-sdk-3-1-for-ios-runs-on-ios6-but-crashes-on-ios-5-x)

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the frameworks to be optional? When you are adding AdSupport.framework, Social.framework, and Accounts.framework, there is drop down menu to the right that you can select between "Required" and "Optional"...

please look at the following link add follow all step...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/