# MonoTouch (Xamarin.iOS) Facebook app switching support for iOS 5+

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there a solution out there where I can happily use the Facebook 3.1+ SDK, with MonoTouch, for iOS 5+ users?

For users NOT using iOS 6 I want my game to switch to the Facebook iOS app for authentication as normal (if they have it), to avoid the barrier of them entering credentials.

The Facebook iOS SDK 3.1+ (Obj-C) allows this functionality, and it uses the native library if users have iOS 6.

Unfortunately I'm unable to find that functionality for MonoTouch, where my app can easily switch to the Facebook app and quickly authenticate the user, for non iOS 6 users.

I've narrowed down my MonoTouch Facebook options to the following, none of them ideal:

1. Limit my game to iOS 6, which would allow me to use the monotouch-bindings/facebook native library
2. Use the Xamarin.Social component, which requires login details (no app switching) and has poor UI
3. Use a (unsupported since 2011) MonoTouch Facebook 3.0 library, there's a couple out there
4. Convert the latest Facebook 3.2.1 SDK to MonoTouch, allowing for non-native app switching

The ideal solution would be option 4, which would give the user the app switching experience on any version on iOS. Unfortunately I wouldn't have a clue where to start with that and I haven't got the time to spend a week trying to convert/bind (?) it.

I'm really not keen on limiting the app to iOS 6 users, we want the app to reach as many people as possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The Monotouch binding for the 3.2.1 facebook SDK is [here](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook).

Last I used it, it seemed to do everything you want.

Comment: I've tried that but it won't work on my iPhone with iOS 5.0.1, it crashes before hitting the UIDelegate. 

Isn't that just for the iOS 6 native library?

Comment: I tried the same code on an iPhone 4S with iOS 6 and that worked ok.

Comment: We didn't have any trouble on a 5.x device, can you post the code that is not working? You might consider a new question.

Comment: I've tried running the FacebookSample, and included MonoTouch.FacebookConnect in my own project's AppDelegate, both won't run on my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1. 

With both it shows the 'evaluation software' message and then quits.

Comment: I think it is related to the issues mentioned in the following question, but I dont know how to fix it for MonoTouch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610078/facebook-sdk-3-1-for-ios-runs-on-ios6-but-crashes-on-ios-5-x

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Xamarin.iOS. Follow the progress on bug fix here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11041