# Facebook iOS SDK: App crashes right after starting with "Symbol not found: _ACFacebookAppIdKey." only in iOS 5

Tags: xamarin.ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Symptoms: app crashes right after starting:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _ACFacebookAppIdKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/C9CCEC42-DD12-40D1-91EE-965A8AC37AE4/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
 in /var/mobile/Applications/1234EC42-0012-40D1-1234-965A8AC31234/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Dyld Version: 199.6
```

This problem is specific to the MonoTouch binding for the Facebook iOS SDK, and it only happens for iOS 5.0 and 5.1. It can be reproduced by simply running [the sample project](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook/samples/FacebookSample) on an iOS 5 device.

There's a related SO question ([Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS - runs on iOS6, but crashes on iOS 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610078/facebook-sdk-3-1-for-ios-runs-on-ios6-but-crashes-on-ios-5-x)) which suggests making the framework optional. As far as I know, this cannot be done from Xamarin.iOS, but the `LinkWith` assembly attribute in the binding already has `WeakFrameworks = "Accounts AdSupport Social"`, which I assume is the equivalent of making those frameworks optional in XCode. So, no help there.

The problem seems to be a bug in the MonoTouch binding, Xamarin.iOS, or the Facebook iOS SDK itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11041) which has been fixed (but the fix hasn't reached any stable version of Xamarin.iOS yet - the bug report says it'll be included in the 6.2.2 release, but that didn't happen).

Currently the only known workaround is to use an older version of the Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 9):

It can be solved very easily..

Click on your project **Targets**.

then go to **summary**

**Under** Linked Frameworks and Libraries

**Change Required Option into Optional of three Frameworks are :**

- Social.framework
- AdSupport.framework
- Accounts.framework

**Now you can also run and check your code on iPAD or iPHONE simulator 5 or 5.1**

Comment: Worked like a charm - Accounts.framework changed to optional.

Comment: Considering this question was for the Xamarin SDK, could you comment on how to add these frameworks to a Xamarin project ? Ive been looking at the IDE for 10 min. Cant believe  something so basic as this is missing / hard to find... OOH wow this is from 2013....

Comment: You can do this configuration if you open it with Xcode.

By other way, this not work for me

Comment: @nVentimiglia Sorry Man its for iOS SDK not for Xamarin SDK :)